# Software to record Skype Conversations for Mac or Windows

Tags: windows, osx, screen-recording, video-conferencing

I've been trying to record skype conversations that I have had with other professionals in my industry to share them among my colleagues.

However, every single time I try to record one of the Skype calls, the audio and video are out of sync.

I've been using quicktime to record the screen, and I have also tried using camtasia without luck.

Comment: What is the issue with Camtasia and Quicktime? What other programs did you try?

Comment: just quicktime and Camtasia. Issue is that audio and video are out of sync. Everything is on the question itself.

Comment: OK thanks, I wasn't sure you had the out of sync issue with both quicktime and Camtasia.

Comment: Before spending money on this, I would make sure the sync works. It sounds very much as if your computer does not have enough processing power to keep the data streams in sync, regardless of the software used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you haven't specified that you want the software to be Open Source (Free), or Premium, I would assume that you are opened to both as Camtasia is Premium.

So try using [Evaer](http://www.evaer.com/) *(Audio and Video Recorder)*

It has wide number of features such as :

- Capture original Skype video and audio data to record with high quality.
- Supports recording single Skype video calls, Skype screen sharing sessions and up to 10 way Skype group video calls.
- Record Skype video calls directly to your hard disk with side-by-side, separate files, audio-only, local-webcam-only and remote-webcam-only mode.
- Changeable recording video codec, video resolution (supports 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p, 1080p), aspect ratio (4:3, 16:9) and frame rate.
- Self-adaptive selection of video resolution and aspect ratio.
- Save Skype video message and Skype voicemail directly to your hard disk.
- Option to record Skype video calls into MP4 or AVI files.
- Option to record separate MP3 audio files with video calls.
- Option to record both sides sound, local sound only and remote sound only.
- Automatically record MP3 audio files if audio calls only.
- Answering machine for Skype video and voice incoming calls.
- Automatic chat reply.
- Easy to use with friendly UI.
- Free download to try and free to upgrade.

To get a detailed information over features, [refer here](http://www.evaer.com/features.htm).

Comment: Amazing, I'm definiteliy going to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be: [Free Video Call Recorder for Skype](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-Call-Recorder-for-Skype.htm#.Uzm0GbGa8YI)
It has nice options:
[image: options menu]
As well as that whole slew of options it is also free and relatively small files (depending on options ofc)

Another handy feature is you can choose to only record audio if you don't care about the video.